# BES Express installer cannot find any Global Catalog servers

Tags: active-directory, blackberry, bes

Quick description of the situtation:

I have a test machine (we need to test our software which talks to BB devices against releases of BES/BES Express) which is running Win Server 08 R2 as domain controller/global catalog (only server in forest). I have installed Exchange 2010 Standard, followed by SQL 2008 Express. Then I ran through the BES Express installer which near the end complained it cannot detect any GC servers and because of this it cannot use Windows authentication. Its running right on one so whats the problem?

I followed the default installation instructions - installed BES as BesAdmin user which is member of Admins, Domain Admins, Domain Users, View-Only Management groups. Everything else was installed as Administrator (member of Enterprise, Domain and regular Admin groups).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've installed BES or BESX so I could be wrong but here's my take:

When installing BESX on a domain controller the besadmin account should be a member of the builtin\Administrators group but not the Domain Admins group.

You should be logged on to the server where BES is to be installed as besadmin, not as Administrator. You should install BESX while logged on to the server as besadmin.

Comment: Sorry, I did install BES as BesAdmin but with wrong privileges. I fixed the privileges (BesAdmin is now member of Administrators and View-Only Management) but the problem persists.